# Unload a whole package or library tree

Tags: package, libraries

Sometimes I want to call `unload-feature` to unload a library… and it a library depends on it… and another library depends on that library…

How can I unload a library and all the libraries that depends on it, without walking through the dependency tree manually?

A common use case is to unload all the libraries of a package (e.g. when upgrading or uninstalling), so if there's a way to do that, it would be good enough.

Answer (score 3):

There's no built-in way to do this--see [Unloading](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Unloading.html) in the Elisp manual.

`unload-feature` takes a `force` argument that allows forcibly unloading `P` even if other packages depend on `P`; is that sufficient for your needs?

If not, you can try to create a recursive version of `unload-feature` containing:

```el
(let* ((file (feature-file feature))
       (dependents (delete file (copy-sequence (file-dependents file))))) 
  (when dependents
    (mapc #'unload-feature-recursive (mapcan #'file-provides dependents))))
```

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the error in the question. Writing a recursive version of `unload-feature` was the point of the question.